# How to apply values from props to styles?

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet, react-native-component

I created a custom component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

const Square = ({size, color, onPress, children}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={styles.sqr}>{children}</View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sqr: {
    width: this.size,
    height: this.size,
    backgroundColor: this.color,
    ...
  },
});

export default Square;
```

As you can see above in the `sqr` style, I try to use the `size` and `color` passed in via `props`.

I use the `Square` in another component in following way:

```
<Square size={30} color="black" .../>
```

However the size and color are not applied when run my app.

So, how can I use passed in values in styles of custom component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of handling conditional styles within your react-native components. In your example, you only have access to `size` and `color` within the `Square` component itself, not the object created by `Stylesheet.create`. In this case, it's common to pass a list of objects to your `style` attribute where you have access to those values:

```
const Square = ({size, color, onPress, children}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View
        style={[styles.sqr, { height: size, width: size, color: color }]}
      >
        {children}
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Since the `style` attribute accepts a list of objects, you can also take this quite a bit further to provide 'active' classes based on props passed to your component. Here's a more complex example if you needed to pass in a style object from a parent and potentially toggle on/off some hypothetical 'active' style:

```
const Square = ({size, color, onPress, otherStyles, active, children}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View
        style={[
          styles.sqr,
          otherStyles,
          { height: size, width: size, color },
          active ? styles.active : null,
        ]}
      >
        {children}
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  active: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I would like to also pass addtional style, I tried this `<View
        style={[styles.sqr, { height: size, width: size, color: color }, otherStyles]}
      >` , but the `otherStyle` doesn't have effect. Why?

Comment: Where is `otherStyle` coming from? Is it an within your `styles`? Or, is it passed in as a prop?

Comment: It is passed in as props. I tried to pass in marginLeft:30,  no effect . `<Square size={30} color="black" otherStyle={{marginLeft:40}}.../>`

Comment: Could you include everything you're now doing? I'm able to properly add additional style objects in that list. I can update my example after I see what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a few more examples to hopefully be more helpful. If your `otherStyle` prop isn't working it might be a typo.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer but have you tried the example I mentioned in my previous comment, does the `marginLeft:40` passed from parent works for you?

Comment: Passing an object with a `marginLeft` attribute is working for me. I did notice in your previous comment that you're referencing `otherStyles` in your `View` component, but you're passing it in as `otherStyle` (notice there's no trailing 's') when you call your `Square` component. Is that a typo in your actual component or just your comment? Also, I've included an `otherStyles` example in my answer which is working for me.